# Why does replacing certificate in WebLogic now require TLS1.2

Tags: ssl, certificate, weblogic, self-signed-certificate

We replaced a self-signed certificate JKS with a signed certificate in WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0.

The C# desktop applications that connect to a service hosted there now fail with "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel".  That can be fixed on the client with 
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` for .NET 4.5 or 
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;` for .NET 4.0.

The two certificates both use SHA256withRSA and a 2048-bit RSA key.

Why did replacing the certificate require the updating the client applications to use TLS1.2?  Also, is there a way to fix this on the WebLogic side so that we do not have to deploy a new version of the client to our users?

**Update**: The old certificate info does not include anything with KeyUsage.  The new one has:

```
#5: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
clientAuth
serverAuth
]

#6: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
DigitalSignature
Key_Encipherment
]
```

The Root certificates also have:

```
#4: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
Key_CertSign
Crl_Sign
]
```

Comment: Are there any differences between the `keyUsage` and `extendedKeyUsage` extensions on the two certs?

Comment: garethTheRed Yes.  Updated question.

Comment: Can you get a replacement certificate with different `keyUsage` and `extendedKeyUsage`?  If so, it might be worth experimenting with different combinations. There is an [answer on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203463/1925616) to a similar question although you should not use the `keyUsage` that worked in that answer!

Comment: Certificates and Ciphers/Protocols have really nothing to do with each other.

TLSv1.2 requirement is probably more due to Java version you are using than anything else, assuming you are also using a recent version of 1.8. I would try adjusting `weblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion` if you want other minimum protocol version. Make sure there have been no recent java updates.